# Your azure function app has functions_worker_runtime set to node while your local project is set to none

Tags: azure-functions

I have a node function app that runs fine locally and when deployed. However, I receive the error : Your azure function app has functions_worker_runtime set to node while your local project is set to none and am unable to deploy it if I don't check in local.settings.json which has the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to node. My arm template app settings has the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to node.

I've tried setting an environment variable during deployment, but it seems like it is reading it out of local settings?

How can I deploy this without checking in the local.settings.json file?

Comment: when you deploy, it will _never_ look at your local.settings file

Comment: i would create a blank node app through azure and see exactly what app settings are configured in the portal for it

Answer (score 26):

I encountered the same error when publishing a function using below command from Travis CI build.

> func azure functionapp publish `<APP_NAME>`

*Error:*

> Your Azure Function App has 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' set to 'node' while your local project is set to 'None'.
>   You can pass --force to update your Azure app with 'None' as a
>   'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'

Resolved it by specifying the language in-line as below,

> func azure functionapp publish `<APP_NAME>` --typescript

Strangely, the publish options listed in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#project-file-deployment) doesn't mention this option. Was able to figure it out with the help of a hint that came along with the error message above.

Comment: Even after almost a full year, this helped me out (although in my case it was --python). Thanks!

Comment: To extend this further the available options seem to be as follows: `--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom`

Comment: Helped a lot! Without this publish of a Timer-based V4 function for windows does not work correctly and no function is seen in Azure Function App.